# Is displaying invalid content a violation on the play store

Tags: google-play-store

I have a suspicious app which requires all sorts of permissions [Omega Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calsto.omega.statusbar&hl=en).

I was facing an issue with the notifications,I reported this behavior to the developer and was surprised to know that the email-id given to contact them under the Email developer does not exist.(got a Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently error)

[image: Reply from the google mail delivery system saying the mail id invalid]
for which i have removed the app after that.Does google has any policy through which i  can report the app as an inappropriate app for having an invalid mail(invalid content displayed)

A link describing the related policy would be much helpfull instead of giving a simple yes or a no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report the app to Google. When visiting the app's page in the web version of the Play Store, there's a link for "[Flag as inappropriate](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2853570?p=report_content&rd=1)".

Under "Malicious or inappropriate Android apps" (and I'd say this probably qualifies) you are given two options for reporting the app. One through the Play Store app on your device, the other via a web site.

> Application providers must adhere to the [Google Play Business and Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/android-developer-policies.html). If you see an application that doesn't follow these standards, you can report it by flagging it from the Google Play Store app on your Android device.
>
> 1. Open the [image: Google Play Store] Google Play Store app.
> 2. Visit the application's page.
> 3. Scroll down and select Flag as inappropriate.
>
> You can also report malicious or inappropriate apps to the Google Play team through the [Android Developer Help Center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/takedown).

Comment: While the app itself might not be "malicious" (though a comment reporting "push ads" might indicate that), the dev might simply have changed the email address and forgotten to update it on Play. Visiting the website looks like the domain has been abandoned (Godaddy placeholder) as well. So no matter what, there's no way to contact the dev but reporting the app to Google to figure out – and maybe leave a comment to warn others this might no longer be supported. +1 from me for the clear guidelines, Al!

Comment: @AI E. This is the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) site now which exact issue do I need to select for fake/in-valid mail id being associated with the application